# How to implement sending a control message once every 5 seconds for each node in the network and send the reply by the receiver

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have made a type of control message called MyControlMessage. Now I want every node to broadcast this type of control message once every 5 seconds and every node that received this type of message should set the value of a field of that message and send it to the source specified in the control message. How is this possible in the Omnet++?

Thanks in advance

NED file is as :

```
network NetworkRM
{
    parameters:
        @display("bgb=900,400");
    submodules:
        visualizer: IntegratedMultiVisualizer {
            parameters:
                @display("p=64.256,62.247997");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                @display("p=64.256,180.72");
        }
        radioMedium: Ieee80211DimensionalRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=62.247997,287.14398");
        }
        source: AdhocHost {
            parameters:
                @display("p=277,45");
        }
        destination: AdhocHost {
            parameters:
                @display("p=522,45");
        }
        source2: AdhocHost {
            parameters:
                @display("p=277,315");
        }
        destination2: AdhocHost {
            parameters:
                @display("p=522,315");
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the NED file of your network?

Comment: Your NED file shows that you want to use `AdhocHost`. Which module/layer of this host are you going to implement your messages?

Comment: It is better to add this ability to send control packets every 5 seconds, at the level of lower layers such as MAC layer, so that it imposes less additional load on the node. Something like adding routing capability to the node. Actually, I don't know the exact answer to your question. Please tell me in which layer or module it is better to add this feature and how?